# Unexpected end of MIME multipart stream. MIME multipart message is not complete. using axios

Tags: node.js, http, axios

I have a problem with uploading files using nodejs, here is the code:

```
failedUrl = settings.getApiUrl() + '/api/organisationupload/' + uploadId     + '/tenant/' + tenantId + '/markAsFailed';
    var boundary = "----7da24f2e50046";
    var data = "";

    data += "--" + boundary + "\r\n";
    data += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"" + "FailedData.csv" + "\"\r\n";
    data += "Content-Type:application/vnd.ms-excel\r\n\r\n";
    //data += "Content-Type:text/plain\r\n\r\n";
    data += failedRowsData + "\r\n\r\n";
    data += boundary + "--";
    context.log(data);

    axios({
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary,
                'Content-Length':  Buffer.byteLength(data)
            },
            data: data,
            url: failedUrl,
            //body: data
        })
```

Then it will have a exception on the .Net API part, here is the code:

```
Task.Run(async () => { await content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider); }).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

It shows:

An exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unexpected end of MIME multipart stream. MIME multipart message is not complete.

I am guessing the axios part is not correct. Anyone has new ideas?